# Integration of tensor to find potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, integration, calculus

I have question given as:
$$\partial_k \varphi = -(C_k+ D_{jk}r_j)$$
where $C_k \,\&\, D_{jk}$ are constants and $D_{jk}$ is symmetric and traceless. I have to find $\varphi$.

I am getting : $\varphi = A -C_kr_k - D_{jk}r_jr_{k}$

but answer is: $\varphi = A -C_mr_m - \frac12 D_{sm}r_sr_{m}$
I am clueless about $\frac12$ term in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer and the official answer are basically the same but they used the fact that the tensor D is symmetric and there is on additional little problem in your solution. Let me start from the beginning:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{k}\phi=-D_{jk}r_{j}
\end{equation}
this expression can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{k}\phi=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\neq k}\left(D_{jk}r_{j}+D_{kj}r_{j}\right)- D_{kk}r_{k}
\end{equation}
Where I just used symmetry.This is easily integrated as:
\begin{equation}
A-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\neq k}\left(D_{jk}r_{j}r_{k}+D_{kj}r_{j}r_{k}\right)- \frac{1}{2}D_{kk}r_{k}r_{k}
\end{equation}
Now since any term that does not contain $r_{k}$ is just a constant in this moment you can and subtract this quantity to the expression:
\begin{equation}
\pm\sum_{s\neq k \;\;m\neq k}D_{sm}r_{s}r_{m}
\end{equation}
where the plus term goes into A and the minus allows you the get the exact expression.

Comment: Btw how do you cancel an extra term,
$$
\pm\sum_{s\neq k \;\;m\neq k}D_{sm}r_{s}r_{m}
$$
I am not getting it, can you explain it?

Comment: The constant of integration is in general a function of $r_{i\ne k}$ and as shown by other methods this function must be a constant plus the negative branch of this term.

Comment: $$( A + \sum_{s\neq k \;\;m\neq k}D_{sm}r_{s}r_{m}) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j\neq k}\left(D_{jk}r_{j}r_{k}+D_{kj}r_{j}r_{k} + \sum_{s\neq k \;\;m\neq k}D_{sm}r_{s}r_{m} \right)
$$
How this simplifies?@ChrisLong

Comment: Well I just meant that since A can be anything that is not a function of $r_{k}$ you can just say that: \begin{equation}A+\sum_{s\neq k \;\; m\neq k} D_{sm}r_{s}r_{m} \rightarrow A\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Physics StackExchange!

If you consider differentiating the third term:

$$\partial_i\left(-\frac{1}{2}D_{jk}r_jr_k\right)$$

First pull the constants put front:

$$-\frac{1}{2}D_{jk}\partial_i\left(r_jr_k\right)$$

Then apply product rule to $r_jr_k$ and see what you get. As this is a homework question I won't go further and want to let you try with this hint, but I am happy to add more if you still don't get it.

Comment: if I go from the answer to the question, I understand that 
$$\frac12 D_{sm}\partial_k r_s r_m =\frac12 D_{sm}(r_m \delta_{ks} + r_s\delta_{km}) = \frac12(D_{km}r_m + D_{ks}r_s) = D_{jk}r_j $$

Comment: but how will I start from question only that : $$\int \partial r_k \ D_{jk}r_j$$

Comment: Correct, so thats your factor of a half as the term is quadratic.

Comment: Well integration is the inverse of differentiating and is normally done by inspection. This is our inspection that we inverse to get the half.

Comment: indeed! Thanks for welcoming on the stack

Comment: I have deleted my last comment realising it was incorrect, appologies for that. But yes what you wrote is correct. So there are three ways to deal with it: 1) use gradient theorem and so integrate by inspection as I suggested. 2) parameterise the r along the curve, change varibales to the parameter and integrate and then substitue back for r. 3) expand out the inner product (implicit summation over k) and integrate as explained in @Yepman's answer.